# NET Beans - MySQL

Tags: mysql, netbeans

I use NETBeans IDE. I want to use JDBC with MySQL. I have downloaded and installed mySQL 5.5 but I don't know how to use mySQL with NETBeans. How can I do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at [the Netbeans documentation](https://netbeans.org/kb/docs/ide/mysql.html) that demonstrates how to set up a connection to a MySQL database from the NetBeans IDE. Take a look at the the section: Configuring MySQL Server Properties

Answer (score 1):

[Here is a very good video tutorial](https://netbeans.org/kb/articles/mysql.html) form  which you can eaisly learn that How to integrate mySQL with netbeans.
Also [see this](https://netbeans.org/kb/docs/ide/mysql.html) for step by step (with pictures) integration
And to setup a mySQL server you [need to see this](https://netbeans.org/kb/docs/ide/install-and-configure-mysql-server.html)

Answer (score 0):

Please see the tutorial below:

https://netbeans.org/kb/docs/ide/mysql.html

Answer (score 0):

@xxlali

- click services under the window tab in the ide.
- right click the database and click new connection
- Add mysql in the driver
- click 'Next'
- type username and password and click test connection.
- Finish once the connection is succeded.